# Windows 8.1 dual-boot with openSUSE boot failure

Tags: linux, boot, windows-8.1, partitioning, opensuse

I already have Windows 8.1 on my newly built PC and wanted to dual-boot with openSUSE. I wrote the install image to a USB, but the install kept hanging so I used network install (also written to a bootable USB).

Before install I created a separate 100 GB partition on my 1 TB RAID1 array that has Windows 8. The partition was created using Windows drive manager. I installed openSUSE on this new partition with no problems, allowing it to autosize its own partitions for boot, swap, etc. After install I tried to use the "boot from local disk" option on the install package on the USB, but I was told that the boot failed.

Without the USB connected, this displays when I try to boot:

δRÉNTFS δRÉNTFS

I cannot advance beyond this point and therefore cannot boot Windows or openSUSE.

When I try to boot from a live CD, I get this:

```
[   4.369837] nouveau E[        PGRAPH][0000:01:00.0] failed to load fuc409c
[   4.369894] nouveau E[        DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] failed to create 0x18000717, -22
[   4.369949] nouveau E[        DRM] failed to create 0x80000080, -22
[   5.801869] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] No Caching mode page found
[   5.801915] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdf] Assuming drive cache, write through
[   36.156720] ata8.00: exception Emask 0x52 SAct 0x0 SErr 0xffffffff action 0xe frozen
[   36.156777] ata8: SError: { RecovData RecovComm UnrecovData Persist Proto HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt CommWake 10B8B Dispar BadCRC Handshk LinkSeq TrStaTrns UnrecFis DevExch }
[   36.156839] ata8.00: failed command: IDENTITY PACKET DEVICE
[   36.156890] ata8.00: cmd a1/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 tag 22 pio 512 in
[   36.156890]  res 40/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x56 (ATA bus error)
[   36.156951] ata8.00: status: { DRDY }
```

Comment: Is secure boot turned on? I know some distros have issues with it and some modern hardware has it turned on by default. What kind of raid array? Does fedora boot? (Its got a signed bootloader so it'll boot off secure boot-enabled systems)

Comment: I have tried with Secure Boot on and off. It is an HDD RAID1 array set up using AMD Option ROM and managed in AMD RAID XPert. And no, all distros I have tried have given me those same error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try booting to an Ubuntu live cd, and running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Comment: When I try to boot from a live CD I get a host of issues, which I added to my post.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the original Windows 8.1 install disk to boot up and refresh the OS, and I am now able to boot Windows successfully. However, still no luck with openSUSE. For now I'm just happy that my PC is functional again.